# The installer needs to remove operating system files from the install target, but was unable to do so.

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb

I have a 1 TB hard disk. And I had reserved 100 GB for the installation for the OS.
40 GB for swap. 
Remaining 800+ GB for home, and another GB for Efi [image]

However when booted from a Live CD, I'm unable to install my OS as it cannot be deleted for some reason.
I receive the following as an error and it pretty much stops there

[image]
What I need to do is, keep my home folder safe and install the linux system in the 100 GB(sda1) partition and making 800 GB(sda3) partition as home
Similar issue was faced by Orfby, but the solution there, doesn't work for me.
It'll be a great help if anyone can suggest me what I did wrong or what I can do to solve this. Thank you !

Comment: Could you please try to format the root partition (with the check box in the column titled “Format?” next to the `/` in the column “Mount point”)?

Comment: I did try that, didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve files on your `/home` partition (`/dev/sda3`) but not on your root (`/`) partition, you can simply check the box under the "Format?" column for root (`/`). This will completely wipe this partition, while leaving `/home` unaffected -- ***IF*** you do ***NOT*** check the equivalent box for it.

If you have any doubts and want to preserve existing data, ***BACK IT UP BEFORE INSTALLING!*** If you lack adequate backup space, then ***GET IT NOW!*** Too many people neglect backups, and it comes back to bite too many of them.

Comment: It did, I also tried formatting the root partition on Gparted, it still gave me the same results, I even tried to install without the /home partition(I could not access it at all),  I faced superblock due to powercut on that 800 gb partition, I couldn't mount it at all, in the end, I had to format it and make a new parition table losing my data.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what you  mean by "*I'm unable to install my OS as it cannot be deleted for some reason*". I agree with Rod, backup what you want to save before fiddling with partitions.

Next, consider the following, assuming you are comfortable being root, using gparted, (un)mounting partitions, editting fstab, etc.

Start the installer and let it **Erase and use the entire disk**. The partitions it creates are a good starting point. When it ends successfully, reboot the new system and just see if you can login. Don't do anything else.

Reboot into the Live CD, mount the huge partition and save the home directory of the user as the previous login session created some useful files in your home directory.

Unmount the huge partition, start **gparted** and shrink that huge partition to the 100GB you wanted. Delete the current swap and create a 40GB swap as you mentioned (dont forget swap-on). Next, create a big partition intended for /home and mount it.
Restore the previously saved home directory into its new location. Make sure the permissions and owner details are correct, otherwise the system may hang after the reboot.
Add the partition info to **fstab** to mount it on /home during boot.

Now the system is ready to reboot with your preferred partitioning.

Comment: I erased the entire disk, I couldn't access the 800 GB partition.
'./e2fsck -p -b 32768 /dev/sda3' didn't work, and other superblocks as well! that returned me with an error asking me to update my e2fsck, I did obviously try to do that but didn't help as well, next time I'll be more careful with my data. So Ultimately I had to make a new partition and start from scratch, few other users also faced this, the above command helped them fix their partition, however some could not. I wonder why is that.

Comment: By that statement I wanted to explain the error I was facing,Even after formatting my 100 gb partition, I couldn't remove it completely and booting my pc would normally give me a grub commandline. my previous installation was / on the 100 gb partition and /home on 800 gb partition. I had done this before and didn't face this error back then.

Comment: What you are describing is instead very strange and it is new to me. So I can only tell you what my thoughts are and what I would do to reset the disk.<br>

Comment: Something else requires my attention, I'll continue later.

Comment: Hi again Schezan.
I started my comment saying your issue was new to me.
Then suddenly I remembered I did encounter a similar situation but it was with an USB stick.
Some time ago the 32GB disk suddenly was reported by the Disk Utility and df -k as 118GB.
I do not remember what caused the issue, but I do remember what I did to resolve it.
I did manage to copy most of the files to another disk, so I was lucky.

Comment: I decided to overwrite the start of the stick (MBR/GPT/Partition table) with 4K of zeroes
and then with 4K of ones. By doing that I was able check if any bits would fall over.
If not, it should be ok to re-create the 32GB stick.
These were my actions:

Create a file of zeroes and a file of ones, then write and read the disk:

Comment: $ truncate -s 4K zerobytes
$ tr '\000' '\377' < zerobytes > onebytes
$ sudo dd if=zerobytes of=/dev/sdb
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb ibs=4K count=1 2>/dev/null | hd -v
$ sudo dd if=onebytes of=/dev/sdb
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb ibs=4K count=1 2>/dev/null | hd -v

I repeated and checked the sudo-actions a few times and found no bits falling over.
Next I used gparted to Create Partition Table and Create Partition and the disk was ok again.
You can do the same with your 1TB disk, but obviously you lose all content.

Comment: Sorry about the last paragraph, the editor removed some linefeeds... The dollars should be seen as line separators.

Comment: I wasn't as lucky, The problem was with my hard disk and it could only be solved by creating a new partition table, even formatting it wouldn't solve it.

Comment: All I want to know now is what caused the problem, all I did was reinstall Ubuntu on sda1 while making sda2 as home. Something must have caused  a bug and made me face a superblock.

Comment: I understand your need to know what happened. Unfortunately I have no answer for you.